# Is all-night Shavu'ot learning as prevelant in the Southern Hemisphere?

Tags: minhag, zemanim, geography, shavuos, evening-night

In the Northern Hemisphere, [Shavu'ot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavuot) falls in the late Spring or early Summer. As a result, sunrise is relatively early, so learning "all night" and then praying the morning service at the earliest optimal time would mean timing the service based on a sunrise of, e.g. [05:36 in Jerusalem in 2012](http://www.myzmanim.com/day.aspx?vars=27526341/5-27-2012////////////////713556).

By contrast, in the Southern Hemisphere, this holiday falls in the late Autumn or early Winter, so the night is longer, and sunrise is significantly later: [06:48 in Sydney in 2012](http://www.myzmanim.com/day.aspx?vars=62814419/5-27-2012////////////////62e6d9) and [07:40 in Capetown in 2012](http://www.myzmanim.com/day.aspx?vars=39154027/5-27-2012////////////////68ca53). As a result, people there who learn "all night" have to stay up an hour or two more into the morning than those in the North.

I'm wondering whether, as a result of this difference, the practice of learning all night is either less prevalent in the Southern Hemisphere, or perhaps whether alternative schedules (such as [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/staying-up-all-night-on-shavuot)) are more prevalent there.

Comment: And with Tzeit at 6PM they get to start much earlier too. So instead of 1130 - 500 it's more like 9-7. That's 10 hours!

Comment: Perhaps they start later?  Before we started our city-wide tikkun I observed start times as late as midnight in the Orthodox community, which is way later than sunset.  Which raises the question of how late you can start and still be valid...

Comment: @MonicaCellio; it's not "Start learning at sunset." It's "you don't pray until sunset+45 minutes [or 42 or 50 or 72 etc.], then allow time to go home, prepare, eat, clean up, then go back to synagogue." So figure to start the learning eh, 3 hours after sunset. Still, we're talking much earlier in the Southern Hemisphere.

Comment: @MonicaCellio [Wow!](http://www.jfedpgh.org/Shavuot2012.aspx)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, this started a few years ago (I think this is #3) and it's great.  It's so nice to have the whole community come together for the first few hours, and then those who want to continue have several options and can go our separate ways.

Comment: @Shalom, right, ma'ariv + dinner etc takes some time, but if you can take any break at all then you can take a longer one, right?  Do you need to start at, say, 10PM, or is midnight or 1AM sufficient?

Comment: Well it wouldn't be much different than Hosha'ana Rabba in NY, would it, and many stay up on that night too.

Comment: @oo, I suspect that many stay up on Shavu'ot in the Southern Hemisphere. I'm wondering if it's less prevalent than it is in the North. Hoshana Rabba all-nighters are much less prevalent to begin with, at least in the places I've been. (Though perhaps they're more prevalent in the South than in the North!)

Comment: @MonicaCellio sufficient for what?  There's no halakha on this AFAIK.  It's minhag.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, "sufficient" in the sense that the (local) community would feel it's honoring the minhag.  Minhagim can be pretty serious stuff even if they're not halacha.  (Consider the different styles of head-covering.)

Comment: Where's [Joe in Australia](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/474/joe-in-australia)?

Comment: One of my rebbeim in Israel once told a story about the time he was invited to be a scholar in residence in Australia for Shavuos.  At least where he was, they did learn the entire night, which was much longer than he was used to from Israel or North America.

Answer (score 10):

I live in Sydney Australia and I can say definitively that yes the custom is to stay up all night and learn on Shavuot night. I have never heard the suggestion that staying up all night is related to the time of sunrise/sunset at that time of year. I have many friends in South Africa and can say that they have the same custom as well.

My inclination is that if you're staying up all night to learn, davening at 5:30 am or at 6:50 am doesn't make too much difference (although if you're right about 7:40am in Capetown that does sound tough).

Comment: BJS, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for sharing your experience! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.