# Why is Tikun Chatzos said specifically at Chatzos? What's so special about Chatzos?

Tags: tefilla, beis-hamikdash, shulchan-aruch, chatzos

The Shulchan Aruch writes in Orach Chaim 1:3

> ראוי לכל ירא שמים שיהא מיצר ודואג על חורבן בית המקדש
>
> It is fitting for every person who has fear of Heaven to be anguished
>   and concerned regarding the destruction of the Temple.

The Mishna Brurah writes on this:

> והמקובלים האריכו מאוד בגודל מעלת קימת חצות כי רבה היא

This is referring to what the world calls Tikun Chatzos.

My question is: Why should a person be anguished concerning the destruction of the Temple specifically at Chatzos? Why is Chatzos special and what makes it special?

Comment: Cf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16703/170

Comment: Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 1:5 אִם אֶפְשָׁר לוֹ לְהַשְׁכִּים וְלָקוּם בַּחֲצוֹת הַלַּיְלָה לַעֲרֹךְ אָז תִּקּוּן חֲצוֹת, מַה טּוֹב, כְּמוֹ שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר, קוּמִי רֹנִּי בַלַּיְלָה לְרֹאשׁ אַשְׁמוּרוֹת וְגוֹ'. וּכְמוֹ שֶׁהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא מְקוֹנֵן בָּעֵת הַהִיא, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר, ה' מִמָּרוֹם יִשְׁאָג וּמִמְּעוֹן קָדְשׁוֹ יִתֵּן קוֹלוֹ שָׁאֹג יִשְׁאַג עַל נָוֵהוּ... וְאִם אִי אֶפְשָׁר לוֹ לָקוּם בַּחֲצוֹת, יִתְגַּבֵּר עַל כָּל פָּנִים לָקוּם קֹדֶם עֲלוֹת הַשָּׁחַר.... וְגַם לְאַחַר חֲצוֹת הַלַּיְלָה, יָכוֹל לַעֲרֹךְ תִּקּוּן חֲצוֹת